# Saving a file in Windows

Tags: java, io

I have a folder called WalnutiQ. Inside this folder is is a file at WalnutiQ/train/model/MARK_II/Save.java

Save.java

```
JsonFileInputOutput.saveObjectToTextFile(myObjectJson,
    "Digits.txt");
```

which works! However, the file Digits.txt is unfortunately saved in WalnutiQ/Digits.txt

How do I save the file Digits.txt at WalnutiQ/train/model/MARK_II/Digits.txt???

I am programming in java in eclipse in windows. I have tried

```
JsonFileInputOutput.saveObjectToTextFile(myObjectJson,
    "/train/model/MARK_II/Digits.txt"); 

JsonFileInputOutput.saveObjectToTextFile(myObjectJson,
    "\\train\\model\\MARK_II\\Digits.txt");
```

but neither work.

Comment: what is the error exception?

Comment: Where are you getting this class from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

judging from the result you are getting your current directory is pointed at WalnutIQ. You might try using .\train\model\MARK_II\Digits.txt. Windows treats the . (period) as a token for "current directory". Your other attempt would have tried to find the train directory in the root of C because the \ (backslash) is a token for the root (c:). It likely fails because that folder does not exist - unless it created it... might go look :) I don't use Json in eclipse which is why I'm not answer your question with code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the full absolute file path to the text file, rather than the relative one you are currently using? This may not be practical, depending on how you plan on using your program, but it might be worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the library saves files (I imagine it's using `File` behind the scenes), you  should be able to supply an **absolute path** to the location you want it to save to.

```
    JsonFileInputOutput.saveObjectToTextFile(myObjectJson, 
                       "/path/to/WalnutiQ/train/model/MARK_II/Digits.txt");
```